# nodejs ws not conecting to the right server

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using the ws module for node.js and I am having a issue, for some unknown reason it isn't connecting to the right server. I am not sure what is causing it to happen. If you need any bits of code just ask. Here is a video of what is happening. https://youtu.be/_Ji50RzyGh4
Here is the connect code:

```
connect() {
    if (this.server == 'none' || this.server == '' || this.server == null || this.server == undefined) return;
    this.ws = new WebSocket(this.server, {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Cookie: '__cfduid=df2db54a70c595c3c2b5a0d067d1650481506608598',
            Origin: origin,
            Referer: origin,
            Pragma: 'no-cache',
            'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
        },
        agent: proxyAgents[this.id]
    });
    this.binaryType = 'nodebuffer';
    this.ws.onopen = this.onopen.bind(this);
    this.ws.onclose = this.onclose.bind(this);
    this.ws.onerror = this.onerror.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in your question, pasted in as text and formatted properly as code.  That's how questions here need to be done.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: Im not sure what code is the problem, i added the connecting code.

Comment: FYI, you can replace the first line of your function with this: `if (!this.server) return;`

Comment: With no sound on the video, there's no explanation of what you are pointing at so the video really isn't telling me anything.  Much better on stack overflow to explain in text in the question.

Comment: If you do `console.log(this.server)` on the first line of your `connect` function, what does it show?  And, what exactly to you expect it to connect to and what is it connecting to?

Comment: When i did `console.log(this.server)` it showed the server that it should be connecting to. I expect it to connect to the current agario server that im in. its connecting to the server i first started on, not the current.